# Fix shade smooth in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there any way to fix that ugly look created by shade smooth? Can I use auto smooth directly in geometry nodes somehow? Because it looks okay with auto smooth, but it is possible only when nodes are applied.

[image: B]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't really be avoided when extruding a mesh with `Extrude Mesh`.

There is, however, an approach with *Geometry Nodes* that will give you a correct smoothing: `Curve to Mesh`.

However, you would have to do it structurally a bit differently:

[image]

Here I first extrude the letters with `Curve to Mesh`, but without *Fill Caps*.

I create the caps manually by placing the letters at the start and end points of the curve along which the letters are extruded.

To make sure that the mesh is closed and has correct normals, I apply the node `Flip Faces` and `Merge by Distance` to connect the individual elements correctly.

[image]

Comment: Let's hope Normal manipulation comes to GN soon

Comment: @RobinBetts Oh yes, I think there are some important nodes on our wish list by now ;-)

Comment: I don't seem to be seeing differences between extrusion and your method. I'm bending it along a curve

Comment: I found a way to do what I wanted. I just need to make that text with auto smooth enabled and just put it as an object then I will have a nice smooth text that I can bend along the curve _inside_ geometry nodes. Guess I can call this a semi-procidural technique